# Virtual CAN Bus silmulator does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, can-bus, socketcan, canutils

I am trying to replay a log file using the following code. It's a very simple code to read each signal from the file and create the command. It is creating the command correctly. I print it to check and it works fine, but when I use  `os.system(command)` to simulate VCAN it freezes and doesn't show the command on the terminal.

```
import os

filename = "canLogs.log"
f = open(filename, "r")
...
(Reading logs from file and create "command")
...

print(command) 
os.system(command)
```

I am using Ubuntu 64-bit (vmWare) on my Mac. This code works fine on Raspberry Pi. And I installed the folllowings:
 `Socketcan` and `sudo apt-get install can-utils` and `pip3 install cantools`. And I bring the virtual can interface by

```
sudo modprobe vcan
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
sudo ip link set vcan0 up
```

To test the interface, when I put this `cansend vcan0 123#1122334455667788` on the command line, doesn't give me any errors. So probably something is wrong with `os.system(command)`, although I checked it by sending other commands. I wonder if I missed isntalling any other libraries in order to use it on Ubuntu (vmWare).

Any help would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: I have used a similar setup without any problem.  You have all the required package and the initialization of the vcan interface is fine.  What happen if you start a python console and just run `os.system("cansend vcan0 123#1122334455667788")`?  And what happen if you remove `os.system(command)` in your script and just leave `print(command)`?  Is the command what you expect to be?

Comment: Something was wrong with the network. It is working now. Thanks